# Cambiar etiquetas de la leyenda

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy intentando cambiar las etiquetas de este gráfico, sin embargo cuando intento con scale_fill_discrete la leyenda se divide en 2, cosa que no se quiere. El comando utilizado fue:

```
ggplot(tocosh_fos, aes(y,x, color = Tratamientos)) + geom_point(aes(color=Tratamientos),show.legend=T)+ stat_smooth(method = "lm",formula = y~poly(x, 3),se=T,show.legend=T,size = 1,alpha = 0.15, aes(fill = Tratamientos))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al utilizar la función scale_fill_discrete solo divide la leyenda como la imagen 2. Y como se haría en caso de que quiera cambiar los colores manualmente tanto del punto como el de la línea (cambiar el color según tratamiento) y también se vea reflejada en la etiqueta?

```
ggplot(tocosh_fos, aes(y, x, color = Tratamientos)) + geom_point(aes(color=Tratamientos),show.legend=T)+ stat_smooth(method = "lm",formula = y~poly(x, 3),se=T,show.legend=T,size = 1,alpha = 0.15, aes(fill = Tratamientos))+ scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("t", "G2","r","4"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Es que tu gráfico tiene dos estéticas `color` y `fill` que apuntan a los mismos datos pero cada una tiene su leyenda. Lo que puedes intentar es algo así:

```
ggplot(tocosh_fos, aes(y, x, color = Tratamientos)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Tratamientos), show.legend=T) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm",formula = y~poly(x, 3), 
              se=T, size = 1,alpha = 0.15, aes(fill = Tratamientos)) + 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("t", "G2","r","4")) +
  guides(fill="none")
```

Detalle:

- Qitamos el `legend = T` de la curva por que de todas formas no vamos a mostrar su leyenda
- Usamos `scale_color_discrete()`, para configurar etiquetas a `color`
- Por último quitamos la leyenda de la estética `fill` mediante `guides(fill="none")`

Comment: Muy agradecido, funcionó bien. pero el color del smooth no sigue la de los tratamientos,  Y si deseo cambiar de color tanto los puntos como la linea ,como podría hacerlo?

Comment: No puedo verificar esto último que dices, el mismo código, por ejemplo usando `mtcars` me respeta el mismo color para las curvas y incluso el sombreado